# Every Click Calling Previous Method Again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How many times should I click the `Click Me 1` button, the more ALERT will popped out when I click the `Click Me 2` button, and it'll show all previous method again!

I want to every click call the exact one method and did not show the last or all previous methods.

If you type any number into the textbox, then click the `Click Me 1` button 3 times, after that click the `Click Me 2` button. It will show 3 times alert box!

```js
$(".get_nubmers_btn").on("click", function() {
  var v_chk_txtbox = $(".numbers_input").val().trim();
  if (v_chk_txtbox.length != "") {
    $(".popup_btn").addClass("foo");
    $(".popup_btn").removeClass("bar");
    $(".foo").click(function() {
      alert($(".numbers_input").val().trim());
    });
  } else {
    $(".popup_btn").addClass("bar");
    $(".popup_btn").removeClass("foo");
    $(".bar").click(function() {
      alert("input an number");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
div.messagebox {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="number" placeholder="insert number" class="numbers_input">
  <button type="button" class="get_nubmers_btn">Click Me 1</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="messagebox">
    <p>Messagebox</p>
    <button type="button" class="popup_btn">Click Me 2</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't add handlers inside other event handlers. Every time the first event happens, you add another event handler to the other elements, so it runs multiple times.

Comment: Just define all your event handlers once at top-level.

Comment: please mention an answer

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates, give me a minute to find one.